# Chrome Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, e4x

Trying to use cdata to store css but chrome throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" for the first line below:

```
var default_style = <![CDATA[
    .TTContent table td.Mission img { max-height: 15px;}
]]>.toXMLString();
```

Does anyone knows why?

P.s. the css is much longer in reality

Many thanks,

Comment: AFAIK Chrome has no E4X support. You can only hope to do this in Firefox (after you fix your syntax a bit I think).

Comment: @Crescent Fresh thanks for the e4x reminder. Yes, that's not correct; the cdata has to be wrapped in an element.

Comment: @Pointy and @Crescent: His syntax is fine. There doesn't need to be an element. A CDATA node is just an E4X text node (`nodeKind() === "text"`), which is perfectly legal.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=235 -- "There are currently no plans for implementing E4X in V8"

Comment: @Eli, @Pointy, and @Crescent: Firefox at least requires it to be wrapped in an XMLList: 
    `var default_style = <><![CDATA[
        .TTContent table td.Mission img { max-height: 15px;}
    ]]></>.toXMLString();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome has no E4X support. You can only hope to do this in Firefox (after you fix your syntax a bit I think).

code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=235 -- "There are currently no plans for implementing E4X in V8"

The code is also incorrect for Firefox:

Firefox at least requires it to be wrapped in an XMLList: `var default_style = <><![CDATA[ .TTContent table td.Mission img { max-height: 15px;} ]]></>.toXMLString();`